# arrange array in a "checkerboard" pattern based on type using javascript and/or underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array of data comprised of tweets and instagram photos that will be displayed on a site in the following fashion:

TWEET | INSTAGRAM

INSTAGRAM | TWEET

TWEET | INSTAGRAM

INSTAGRAM | TWEET

The amount of tweets in the array is much greater than the amount of instagram photos, but I want to make sure that, regardless of the number of items in the feed, the results alternate in this fashion. How can I rearrange the array most efficiently such that I keep to this pattern? I can only use javascript, jquery, or underscore.

Comment: Do certain tweets go with certain instagrams, or is the pairing completely random/arbitrary?

Comment: completely arbitrary, just needs to alternate between types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you will need to implement a couple of JS functions as follows:

```
function getElements() {
    // to be implemented by you, returns an array
}

function elementIsTweet(elem) {
    // to be implemented by you, returns a boolean
}
```

A couple of assumptions were made here.  A big one is that we quit processing once the tweets or the instagrams have been exhaused.  It should also be noted that intermediate results are collected in arrays.  For large sets, it would probably be more efficient to keep track of multiple indexes when building the resulting array.  But the code started getting pretty messy :)

```
// this returns a single dimensional array,
// alternating between tweets and instragram
function getAlternatingArray() {
    var arr = getElements();

    // break array into separate parts
    var tweets = [], instagrams = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (elementIsTweet(arr[i])) {
            tweets.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            instagrams.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    // re-combine
    var newArr = [];
    var isTweet = (Math.randon() < .5);
    while (true) {
        var currArr = isTweet ? tweets : instagrams;
        if (currArr.length == 0) {
            break;
        }
        newArr.push(currArr.shift());
        isTweet = !isTweet;
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Finally, it is pretty trivial to create a "checkerboard" multi-dimensional array once you have a single-dimensional array with alternating item types.

```
function checkerBoardArray(columns) {
    // Error checking should be added to validate that columns is *even*
    var arr = getAlternatingArray();
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i * columns < arr.length; i++) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < columns && i * j < arr.length; j++) {
            row.push(arr[i * j]);
        }
        newArr.push(row);
    }
    return newArr;
}
```